# Searching arrayLists

Tags: java, search, arraylist, indexing

Hi im creating a simple mp3 database that stores a trackNum, name and duration. I need to search an array list and get the index of the search.

Here is what i have at the moment.

```
//My methods
public void searchTrackNum(Intager trackNumber){
    System.out.println(trackNum + ": " + name[index] + " " + duration[index]);
}
public void searchName(String name){
    System.out.println(trackNum + ": " + name[index] + " " + duration[index]);
}

//Using the methods
case 4:
    System.out.println("What name would you like to search for: 1-Track Number or 2-Name");
    int question = in.nextInt();
        if(question == 1){
            System.out.println("Please enter the track Number?");
            meth.searchTrackNum(in.nextInt());
        }
        if(question == 2){
            System.out.println("Please enter the Name?");
            meth.searchName(in.next());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Pease enter 1  or 2.");
        }
    break;
```

1. How do i search an arrayList
2. I need to be able to get the index of the search to add the name of the track and the duration of it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using

```
int index = Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(nameToLookFor);
```

If the names are sorted, you can use binarySearch instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this is what i have done.           'public void searchName(String aName){
   int num = Arrays.asList(name).indexOf(aName);
   System.out.println(trackNum + ": " + name.get(num)+ " " + duration.get(num));
  }'

Comment: The program just crashes when i search for a name

Comment: In that case I suggest you read the error message, it might be trying to tell you something. ;)  What does it say?  Something like `ArrayIndexOutOfboundException: -1` ?

Comment: Exactly that, what would cause that

Comment: The Javadoc of List.indexOf says that `-1` is returned if a match is not found.  i.e. the string you are looking for is not in the array.  This is where using a debugger helps. ;)

Comment: the string i searched for was just entered, what do you suggest now.

Comment: Use the debugger to see why the string you think should be is not.